# How to make a serial number form? with "-" split in the middle

Tags: java, javascript, html, regex, jsp

I want to make a form on HTML for users to submit a serial code. It looks like this:

XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

But I don't want the users to manually type in the "-"s.

I have two possible solutions in mind.

1. My first plan is I make multiple < input > for each section, And add a tab index, but that is still too hard for phone users, because Android doesn't have TAB like feature to scroll through the 6 < input >s. Which means they'll have to deal with tapping the super small input boxes and experience the glitchy keyboard popping up and down.
2. I could make it so that the textbox is controlled with Javascript and make it check the box and split the code with "-" automatically. But imagine if you have

> 01-02-03-09-05-06

and you want to change the "09", if the user deletes the "9" it will glitch and look like this:

> 01-02-03-00-50-6

which in my opinion is not good enough. I want to make it perfect for the user.

So how do the professionals do it? Is it possible that the cursor in plan 1 can automatically jump from one < input > to the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an awesome jquery plugin for this kind of inputs:

https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

code:

First, include the jQuery and masked input javascript files.

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Next, call the mask function for those items you wish to have masked.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

Optionally, if you are not satisfied with the underscore ('_') character as a placeholder, you may pass an optional argument to the maskedinput method.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

Optionally, if you would like to execute a function once the mask has been completed, you can specify that function as an optional argument to the maskedinput method.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask("99/99/9999",{completed:function(){alert("You typed the following: "+this.val());}});
});
```

and so on...

Comment: Will the place holders actually be included when the form is sent? or is it just place holder?

Comment: It's only a placeholder, when you type in some numbers the placeholders are gone. the `-` stay there. as you wanted :)

Comment: Although there is still a problem with : 01-02-03-00-50-6 But I guess this is already the best/easiest way to do it.

Comment: This reminds me of: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif You don't need jQuery or any library for this.

Comment: Just use JQuery. It's great and does everything.

Comment: why should there be a problem @Louie? You can just edit the code to your needs :).

Comment: I was just about to start a JQuery tutorial when @KeesSonnema came and told me I could do it with native javascript. lols, I figured If I do it his way I can get the exact results as the JQuery Plugin would. Then why waste 77KB or our users bandwidth. (I'm just to lazy to learn JQuery, Heh :)   )

Comment: JQuery is reaaally easy, but no problem.

Comment: @KeesSonnema I just found out 2 seconds ago, It IS really easy. I will consider you're solution in future cases! Thank you for telling me about this plugin

Comment: Link is broken, page 404s now

Comment: @Rainb https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

Answer (score 2):

Just use native JavaScript. You don't need jQuery for something as simple as this.

What you need to do is check the length of the entered string. If this is 2, 5, 8, 11, ..., automatically add a dash. The next condition will return `true` for these values: `value.length % 3 == 2`. You should check this on the `keydown` event, since this fires after the the user enters something.

```
document.getElementById('serial').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    var value = this.value;

    // 17 is the max length of the serial XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
    if (value.length < 17) {
        if (value.length % 3 == 2 && value.substr(value.length - 1, 1) !== '-') {
            this.value = this.value + '-';
        }
    }
}, false);
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hBHbM/1/)</kbd>

Comment: @KeesSonnema This was my original plan though, but I thought there would be a magical way to to prevent this: 01-02-03-00-50-6 from happening. But now that I think of it, it's not that much of a problem I guess......(Considering the amount of effort) I'll probably use you're solution.

Comment: I'm not sure which one I should give the green mark to...  Because both of you're answers are very good answers.

Comment: If you check this answer as the right one you could upvote mine, if you not already did :) it's fine tho

Comment: I found a solution for that, if you add `value.substr(value.length - 1, 1) !== "-"` to the second if condition it will prevent that from happening. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The code glitches when when a user types too fast. Maybe it's better to loop through the string rather then adding to it.

Comment: I think this is coming to a point where the jQuery seems better

Comment: Woops, nevermind, changing the event from "keyup" to "keydown" fixes the problem. Native javascript wins

Comment: @Broxzier Does stackoverflow encourage that? Or is it better to let the original author change it?

Comment: @Louie: That's perfectly fine. It has to be reviewed and accepted by someone with 2k+ reputation anyway (and you got a badge I think).

Comment: I tested the script further and I find it's extreamly glitchy when I try to delete the serial in the textbox. This is not the solution after all.... There's way to much to consider.

Comment: @Louie: It's an example of how it's done. Ofcourse it needs more checks to prevent these things from happening.